# Static Class not loaded

Tags: java, class, constructor, static, static-constructor

Im familiar with C#, learning static class in Java nowadays. 
in the code below, I assumed if staticClass constructor is already initialized at startup. but it is not. When debug cursor reach the breakpoint of first for loop in main method. I get an error "staticClass not loaded".

Question: is there a way to execute static class constructor before main method executed? or why its not loaded ? similar static class is loaded in C# at startup. but in java ? consider that this is a not working code. as an java expert, how you could rewrite this code ? as it should corrected.

```
public class Main {

    public static class staticClass
    {
        public static int myArray[];

        public staticClass()
        {
            myArray=new int[10];
        }

        public static int NextUnique()
        {
            int r=(int)(Math.random()*10);
            return r;
        }
    }
    //=new int[10];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        for (int i=0;i<staticClass.myArray.length;i++)
            staticClass.myArray[i]=  staticClass.NextUnique();

        for(int i=0;i<staticClass.myArray.length;i++) {
            String msg= MessageFormat.format("{0}. value= {1}",i,staticClass.myArray[i]);
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A nested class is just like a tp-level class, except it's nested in another class and has access to its enclosing class private members. It behaves as any other class. And its constructor will thus not be magically invoked if you never call it anywhere.

Comment: I dont like to embed a class into another, but I think this is the only way in java. can a static class be alone / unnested?.

Comment: Sure, except in that case, you don't need the static keyword. It just becomes a top-level class, like your Main class. I'm not sure what you mean by "It's the only way". The only way to do what?

Comment: to declare a static class. a static class have to be nesten in another class. as I read documentations. its the only way.

Comment: Well, if you don't want a nested class, don't use one. Just use a top-level class. The static keyword is only used to differentiate between a nested class, and an inner class. What do you think a nested class can do that a top-level class can't? What do you think the static keyword does in this context?

Comment: static class staticCls
    {
        public static int Var1 = 15;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(staticCls.Var1);
        }
    }


this is C# simplest example. its not possible in java. or is it ? I expect a static class can have a self singleton, can hold variables, methods, objects during app lifetime without generating any instance.

Comment: Well, yes: `public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Other.var1);
    }
}

class Other {
    public static int var1 = 15;
}`. But Other is just a class. As any other class. It's NOT a singleton. There's no such thing in Java (other than by using the singleton pattern). Making it a nested class doesn't change that. static doesn't transform a class to a singleton in Java (as you seem to imply it does in C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a static static initialization block (constructor) for this purpose. Instead of

```
 public staticClass()
    {
        myArray=new int[10];
    }
```

use

```
 static
    {
        myArray=new int[10];
    }
```

Your constructor right now is instance constructor. It works whenever you use new operator. See [static constructor in c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx) and [static initialization block (constructor) java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: THat's not a static constructor. It's a static initialization block. Thre is no such thing as a static constructor in Java.

Comment: @JBNizet C# comers know it as a static constructor. It works same way. I already added links. And questioner said that "I'm familiar with C#".

Comment: Maybe that's the term in C#. But not in Java. Terminology is important. A constructor constructs an instance.

Comment: It is duck test.  "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck" static initialization block and static constructor works same way. They are same thing with different names.

Answer (score 1):

You can just initialize the array like this:

```
    public static int myArray[] = new int[10];
```

Comment: its okay. thank you. but not the question's answer. question is this. why constructor is not executing at startup ? and why static class is not loaded.

Comment: OK, JB Nizet gave the short answer in his comment: constructors are not called unless the object is created.